# GIT локальный и удаленный репозиторий

Tags: git, windows-10

Итак я разрабатываю проект. Использую open server. Хочу подключить контроль версий. Вывешать на всеобщее обозрение мои труды пока не хочу. Соответственно вопрос: возможно ли использовать контроль версий локально так, чтобы все и каждый файлы моего проекта оставались на моем компьютере windows 10, и буквально не одна муха из моего проекта не попала в сеть либо тем более другим разработчикам

Comment: конечно можно. Просто не добавляйте удалённый репозиторий. Правда, если с диском что-то произойдёт то всё потеряете, так что советую использовать приватный репозиторий на каком-то хостинге (bibacket к примеру бесплатно даёт создавать приватный репозиторий).

Comment: @pavel, github, вроде, после перехода к мелкомягким, тоже разрешает бесплатно приватные репозитории использовать)

Comment: GitForWindows подойдет для локального хранения?

Comment: GitForWindows - это просто графическая оболочка для Git. Никакой дополнительной функциональности или ограничений она не вносит.

Answer (score 5):

Короткий ответ: Да!

Длинный ответ:

Git, как *распределенная* система контроля версий, в каждом "клиенте" содержит полноценный "сервер". Ваша локальная копия уже является полноценным сервером.

Связь с внешним миром нужна только в том случае, если вы хотите обмениваться изменениями (команды push и pull/fetch). При этом даже для нескольких разработчиков в пределах локальной сети "сервер" не обязателен, можно напрямую обмениваться между локальными копиями.

Answer (score 3):

Разумеется, можно. Так же как интернету не нужен git для работы, так и git'у не нужен интернет для работы. Если бы гиту был обязательно нужен интернет, то им бы ни пользовались в организациях - мало кто захочет выгружать код своих продуктов в открытую сеть. Все лежит в локальной сети. Но даже и локальная сеть не нужна - удаленным репозиторием можно назначить другую папку на этом же компьютере. Написать в   `.git\config` что-то вроде

```
[remote "host"]
    url = S:\\projects\\git\\my_project
```

и тогда эта папка будет "внешним" репозиторием.

Или же вообще не создавать внешний репозиторий, и держать все в одной папке. Но это противоречит элементарным принципам хранения данных, поэтому так лучше не делать - лучше бэкап хотя бы на другом диске, чем вообще никакого.